# how to get the stat information for war file using perl

Tags: perl, clearcase, perl-data-structures

I have Perl script that gets stat information for a given file. But it does not work for `.war` file. (This file has symbolic link.)

I am passing file location which has multiple files.

`$fntxt` points to `/dw/xyz/file1.txt`. `file1.txt` has `/vob/vob1/test.war`.

Executing `@Stats=stat($ln);` returns an empty array for a `.war` file.

```
open(DAT, $fntxt);
@fnames=<DAT>;
close(DAT);
print "@fnames\n";

foreach $ln (@fnames)
{
    chomp $ln;
    $i = length $ln;   
    if ($i>0)
    {     
    @Stats=stat($ln);
    if (!@Stats)
    {
        print "File [$ln] specified in [$fntxt] does not exist. Correct then rerun.\n";
        exit 255;
    }

    ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst)
         = localtime((stat($ln))[9]);
    $mon += 1;
    $year += 1900;

    $tstamp = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d.%02d",
        $year,$mon,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perl [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function should return values for symbolic links as well. Try to print out the error container variable `$!` to get the real error message.

Comment: use `$!` to see why `stat()` failed: `@Stats = stat($ln) or die "unable to stat $ln: $!"`
Also - there is no need to `stat($ln)` twice - just use `@Stats` in your `localtime(...)` call.

Comment: You want to use `lstat` for symbolic links.

Answer (score 0):

With a symbolic link (assuming some flavor of unix) you want the permissions on the file being linked to, not the link.  Use -l to detect that the file is a symbolic link and readlink to find out what it is linked to.  If there are multiple links (i.e. link to link ...) follow them until you find the file.

Comment: /vob implies clearcase.  All bets are off if that's the case.  It's not a normal unix file system.